# Using Custom Post Type of One Theme in Another Theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I was doing a client project. They needed to change the theme and the theme is really complex to change the code and manage. They are also using Visual Composer. And when i used the new theme. It's not that much compatible. So they have a CPT in the theme before called Events, Edge Carousel and more. So that is really important for them. And these CPT don't work on the new theme.

Comment: What is your question? Your problem is still not clear.

Comment: Some themes come with special functionallity (like plugins) e.g. as mentioned elements (Carousel), data (Custom post types) and templates (the page that displays the custom posts).
When you change the theme the theme specific functions are not working any longer. SO you have to create your own! Like the VisualComposer: when deactivating it, the page will no longer look like it was unit then.
Have a look at the old theme and search for the functionallity/templates/etc. 
Try to include in yout new theme.

Comment: My Question was just how to include the CPT in new theme and Make the VIsual Composer compatible with my new theme and the CPT that are not visible in the new theme.